# Sending PDF through WhatsApp in Android

Tags: android, whatsapp

My intention is to send a PDF file via whatsapp through my application.What happening now is its not opening whatsapp appliation.Below is my code:

```
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                //share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("application/pdf");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,""));
```

Comment: Do you get any error in logs ?

Comment: No error in logs. @B.M

Comment: weird, your code worked fine on my vm, are you sure you have whatsApp installed on your testing device ?

Comment: Yes its installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you don't need to create chooser, and I hope you want to directly share to WhatsApp.

> **Whatsapp Documentation** : 
>    If you prefer to share directly to WhatsApp and bypass the system picker, you can do so by using setPackage in your intent.

[WhatsApp Documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012/)

```
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
 Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 share.setType("application/pdf");
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
 share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 startActivity(share);
```

**Edit**

For target Sdk 24 or above you need to use `FileProvider` class to be able to use specific file.
follow directions which are listed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203508/2930834).

Comment: This logic was my first try. Unfortunately this too dosen't works.

Comment: Ahhh... Damn it... 
Can you provide your respective log entries ? 
Just a suggestion to include try-catch and print all exceptions ...

Comment: What is  your targetSdkVersion ? Is it 24 or higher ?

Comment: Targetversion was 26

Comment: check this link answer, You need to handle this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203508/2930834

Comment: This trick done my job. Please post this as answer. i will accept. Thanks

Comment: Updated answer.