# Viewing .PDF file in Android App - any Phonegap plugin(s) available?

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, androidpdfviewer

I'm developing phonegap application for android devices. I want view the pdf inside my app without having sharing or email options. Just want user to view the pdf. I know the inappbrowser will not work for android. Is any other in-build plugin available for android.? Please help me out.

I've tried file opener and pdf view plugin. not yet helped.

```
var options = {
  showButtons: 0, //0: no buttons; 1: ok button, 2: ok and cancel button
  cancel: "Cancel", //text for cancel button
  ok: "OK" //text for ok button
};
PDFViewer.showPDF(decodeURI(devicepath), options, function (result) {
});
```

Others

```
window.open(decodeURI(devicepath), '_blank', 'location=yes,EnableViewPortScale=yes');
```

//                          openPdfInFileOpener2Plugin(decodeURI(devicepath));

Comment: which plugin you are using currently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245953/i-am-trying-this-code-to-share-pdf-fromasset-of-app-but-its-showing-error/58246526?noredirect=1#comment102970943_58246526
you can take help from this, i had posted the answer here

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm looking for like iOS inappbrowser plug functionality. I mean, need open my local/online PDF file to view the use without share or download option.