# Android share pdf from a url

Tags: java, android

I have a url with a pdf file and i would like to show a share via intent on button click

SO i have the following

```
 string pdfurl = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
```

SO in my code i have

```
public function showShareIntent(String url){
   Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("application/pdf");

     //attach pdf here
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfurl);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share sample item via"));

 }
```

But the above doesnt attach the pdf file

What am i missing out
I have checked on [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522482/how-to-share-pdf-and-text-through-whatsapp-in-android) but it expains loading this when file is located on local device.

How do i attach a url pdf file when showing share.

Comment: You can not share file a remote file with `Intent` . You need to download it first and then pass the local Path of the file To Intent .

Answer (score -1):

Step #1: Download the PDF.

Step #2: Share it using `FileProvider` via `EXTRA_STREAM`.

That way, you follow [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) and use a `content:` `Uri`.

Alternatively, include the URL in some message in `EXTRA_TEXT`.